# Windows 10 - How to use an alias of a command?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, terminal, powershell

I'm new to Windows and I know how to do it in Unix systems. In Windows 10, suppose that I want, in my Windows Command Processor, that the command `d` permanently does exactly the same as `cd` then `ls`, how would I do this ?

For instance, I'm in this Command Processor, and when I type `d C:Users`, this is equivalent of doing `cd C:Users` + `ls` and that goes then lists all my files and directories in this folder.

EDIT thanks to @montonero :
You can replace the "Windows Command Processor" by "PowerShell" and my question still remains :D

Comment: @Biswapriyo then how could I to this with environment variables? I'm open to any workaround.

Comment: You can use Doskey for this, but to have the macro persistent you'll have to store it/them in a file and use an autorun to have them loaded automatically.

Comment: @LotPings, as I'm new to Windows, these are new terms for me, could you please write your workaround and its steps as an answer to my question? Then I'll select it when I'll succeed doing it :D

Comment: The macro to use (non persistent) is `doskey d=cd /d $*$Tdir`

Comment: @LotPings Thank you, so this is a partial answer to my question if I correctly understood, what about the autorun part?

Comment: I did elaborate on this in my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1141036/keyboard-shortcut-to-select-current-console-input-in-cmd)

Comment: @J.Khamphousone You could try Powershell instead of cmd. It has native aliases, configurable profile and lot more.

Comment: @montonero, Thank you, I've edited my question according to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do what I wanted thanks to @montonero suggesting me to move to PowerShell.

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases) and its second answer by Chase Florell using this code for PowerShell script .ps1:

```
function ShortCut-cd ($1){
    cd $1
    ls
}

Set-Alias d ShortCut-cd
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows cmd you would save this as, say, `cddir.cmd` somewhere in your path:

`cd %1
 dir`

Then run `cddir \data`

But I too prefer the powershell answer if you work in powershell

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would rather name it `c.cmd` rather than cddir because the point of my command was saving time each time I use change directory command :)

Comment: You can call it anything you want!